# pagination in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, laravel-5

I'm having some trouble implementing pagination in Laravel 5. Though probably not what you would think.
I can get everything to work but can't understand how to get it to pull the correct information on the second page.
Here is what I have:

**Routes:**

```
Route::resource('find-a-wp-theme', 'searchController');
```

**Controller:**

```
public function store(){


        $themes['themes'] = Fulls::where("tags", "like", "%".$_POST['theme']."%")->orwhere("tags", "like", "%".$_POST['free']."%")->orwhere("title", "like", "%".$_POST['free']."%")->paginate(12);

        return view('find-a-wp-theme', $themes);

   }
```

**View:**

```
@if($themes)                                

        @foreach($themes as $theme)

        {{$theme['title']}}<br />
        <img style="width:250px;" src="{{$theme['image']}}"><br />

        @endforeach
        {!! $themes->render() !!}


    @endif
```

Up till here everything works just fine. My problem is that when I click the paginating button it takes me to mypage?page=2 which actually takes me to the resource `index()` and I can't understand how to implement this correctly.
Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at append in the docs. http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/pagination

If your trying to pass variables in your URL you need to use appends().

```
<?php echo $users->appends(['sort' => 'votes'])->render(); ?>
```

Comment: That was very helpful, thanks!
However that brings me to a different issue. 
I want to add the parameters in the pagination URL but am getting the full php in it.
I tried using {{{$param}}} and {!! $param !!} and {{ $param }}, nothing seems to work.
Thoughts?

Comment: Ok, figured it out. Even though its in blade you need to add the parameter with nothing surrounding it.